# Python 2.7 @property usage results in error "global name '_c__pro' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, properties, encapsulation

I wrote a simple class in Python2.7 that should use the `@property` functionality.

```
class c():
    def __init__(self):
        __pro = 1

    @property
    def pro(self):
        return __pro *10

    def setpro(self, x):
        __pro = x
```

Now when I create an object from this class and try to access the `pro` property, I get the following error:

```
>>> x = c()
>>> x.pro
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in pro
NameError: global name '_c__pro' is not defined
```

Note that the whole thing was written inside the same python commandline-session, so it should have nothing to do with missing imports or wrong import namespaces.

What am I doing wrong here? How must I rewrite it to access the property `pro`?

Comment: Actually make it a *property* on `self` instead of a local variable...!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `self.` when accessing member variables:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__pro = 1

@property
def pro(self):
    return self.__pro *10
```

Comment: Of course! _(facepalm)_ Sometimes the easiest mistakes are the hardest ones... I'll accept in 9min, as soon as the delay is over.